# Selenium not picking up found elements on xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Found list of elements either with xpath or CSS (same results in browser console)

```
int alltips = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='column medium-12']//div/ul/li")).size();
int alltips1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.feed-tips#Grid > li.feed-item")).size();
    System.out.println(alltips);
    System.out.println(alltips1);
```

As a result of both printing got same result (that there are 21 of 'li' containers exist on a page)
But, when put ran that in selenium webdriver, I got same result for both and it is zero.
Added screenshot from console

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Here is a part of HTML:

```
<div class="column medium-12">
<h1>Free Tips</h1>
 <p>Here you'll always find the latest tips posted by our international    community of sports betting tipsters. If you're ever in need of inspiration for a bet, this is the place to be! </p>
 <div class="row">
 <ul class="feed-tips" id="Grid" data-sport="" data-country="" data-
  league="">
```

And below HTML looks like  as on screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Share the `HTML` please.

Comment: @DebanjanB Unfortunately, it is not live, so I will sent you here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findElements` does not throw an error if no elements are found, so it is possible that the elements are not found at the time of calling this method.

You can wait for the `ul` element to be visible before calling `findElements` by using a `WebDriverWait` like this

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(#Grid)));
```

This will wait **up to** 10 seconds before throwing a timeout. After that, call your `findElements` method. At this point you know that the parent `ul` is visible

```
int alltips = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='Grid']/li")).size();
```

Comment: It does not throw any error - in browser it found all li elements and when  ran that test as a part of testsuite it show zero elements. 
There is not any error 
Also, it waits 4 seconds after page is opened

Comment: That's what I said. It does not throw an error. Since it does not throw an error, you don't know for sure that your elements are indeed available for the webdriver to find. That's why you should wait for the `ul` tag to be visible before trying to find the `li` children.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!